# Homemade controls in WP7 Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7 Silverlight, is there a way to design a custom control from scratch - i. e. with custom drawing and custom touch processing? What do I subclass for that?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. You usually subclass Control, ItemsControl, or ContentControl. Here is a blog post that explains the process in detail: [Creating a WP7 Custom Control in 7 Steps](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-WP7-Custom-Control-in-7-Steps)

Comment: Neither drawing nor touch processing in that example... Just a combination of primitives.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by drawing, almost all controls are simply collections of primitives built into a more interesting control. In terms of touch processing the Control class has the Manipulation events for you to hook into touch events.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can create a custom control from scratch by deriving from the `Control` class. To implement gesture handling you can use the `GestureService` from the [Silverlight Toolkit for WIndows Phone 7](http://silverlight.codeplax.com) or you can directly handle the `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta`, and `ManipulationCompleted` [`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590079%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) events.

Jeff Prosise has a great series of four posts that cover touch manipulation in great detail:

- [Part 1](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-2.aspx)
- [Part 3](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-3.aspx)
- [Part 4](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/01/14/building-touch-interfaces-for-windows-phones-part-4.aspx)

For the "custom drawing" part, what did you have in mind? If a control built up from primitives isn't what you had in mind, what about [lines and shapes](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-1-getting-started-and-line-shape)?

Comment: Lines and shapes on the XAML level... An old joke about XML comes to mind. Here goes: <bitmap><row><pixel red="100" blue="200" green="0"/></row></bitmap>